# Getting server too busy error at first login

Tags: .net, windows, session, iis

0 Points
1 Post
Getting server too busy error at first login
3 minutes ago|LINK

Hi,

I have a website hosted on IIS 7, running on Windows 2008 R2. I have a very strange problem that we are facing with the websites hosted on this server. The first time I try to open the website for the day, i get a message "The service is unavailable. Server too busy." When I refresh the page, I am able to go to the login page.

After opening the website and logging in, the first transaction I try to do - I get a 'Session time out' message which we have custom built whenever a session expires, and I am logged out of the website.

After logging in again, the website now functions normally and without any issues. The Session time out is set to 20 minutes, and InProc. I am not able to figure out, what may be bothering my website and how to go about debugging the issue as the issue occurs only once when we login for the first time on the website. the website does not have a very heavy load, so no one logins during the night.

Any help would be highly appreciated. The website is running on Application pool v4.0 (Classic - Managed pilpeline mode)

Thanks,

Pushpreet

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].